# Retrieving geometry objects from hibernate to angular.js

Tags: java, hibernate, angularjs

I'm trying to view some objects on a map which are stored in postgreSQL db. The frameworks used are spring and hibernate with angular.js for the front end. I have checked the controler class, service class for the returned objects from hibernate. At the class level they are fine. But when I check the js (angular.js) it has objects and numbers. Due to that an error occurs since the code expect objects instead of numbers. The return object is similar to this.

```
Array[5]
   0:Object
   1:20
   2:Object
   3:24
   4:13
   length:5
```

The Array contains the results returned from the controller class. First object is viewed on the map. since the second one is a number instead of an object it generates an error.
This the code block which return the objects to the angular.js script.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/crimerecode/getall.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public List<CrimeRecord> getAllCrimeRecords(@RequestParam String startDate,@RequestParam String endDate) {
    try {
        // crds.invalidateCrimeRecord(cr.getGcrno());
        System.out.println("=========controller===============");
        for(int i=0;i<(crds.getAll(startDate, endDate)).size();i++){
            System.out.println(((crds.getAll(startDate, endDate)).get(i).getTheGeom()));
        }
        return crds.getAll(startDate, endDate);
    } 
    catch (ParseException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CrimeRecordController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return null;
}
```

This is the code block in the angular script...

```
$http.get('/CMISystem/crimerecode/getall.htm?startDate=' + $scope.startDate + '&endDate=' +
            $scope.endDate
            ).
            success(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                alert(data);
        data.forEach(function(value) {

            console.log(value);

            var geo = value.theGeom.geo;

            var point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(geo.lon, geo.lat);
            point.transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), map.getProjectionObject());
            var pointFeature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(point, value);
          .....
         }
```

I have only post the relevant piece of code in classes and javascript in here...

Comment: I can't post the screen shot of the error since my rep is low....but the array I have typed can provide some sense regarding this problem I hope....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with the `List<CrimeRecord>` you return from your `getAllCrimeRecords` method.

Try creating an array list and add each `CrimeRecord` object, to your array list as shown in the following example.

> ```
> public List<CrimeRecord> getAllCrimeRecords(@RequestParam String startDate, @RequestParam String endDate) {
>         List<CrimeRecord> cr = new ArrayList<CrimeRecord>();
>         try {
>
>             for (int i = 0; i < (crds.getAll(startDate, endDate)).size(); i++) {
>                cr.add(crds.getAll(startDate, endDate).get(i));
>             }
>
>         } catch (ParseException ex) {
>             java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CrimeRecordController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
>         }
>
>         return cr;
>     }
> ```

Comment: Yes, It worked...I changed the controller class's method and then I received results as objects....but still have no idea why some returned as objects and some as numbers....Anyway this solves my problem...